# How and when would I use a Rake file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, makefile, rake

I have been programming for about a year now and have begun exploring new topics now that I have a solid grasp of the fundamentals of computer science.  I've been doing a lot of web development stuff lately, especially with RoR, and I'm totally confused about what a Rakefile is.  I've looked around on the internet for some explanations, but most of what I've seen has been stuff that says "Rake is a ruby version of Make" or "You can build a file from scratch with it" or "You can write your own tasks!". Unfortunately, I don't know what Make is (I would assume an older version of Rake, but since I havent used it, that doesnt help me understand what Rake is), I don't know why I'd need a special file to make new files on the fly for a web-app, and I don't really understand what tasks are/how to use them.

So, my question is, how exactly is Rake used, both in web apps and in other areas of programming? When is it run in a program and what does it accomplish? Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rake, Make, Lake, Waf, Ninja, CMake and all its ilk are project *build tools* designed to execute commands and carry out tasks based on a *dependency relationship*, typically expressed as a graph. When you write a script file for any of these systems, it's usually written in a domain specific language. For the record, Make *isn't* an older version of Rake. They are two completely independent tools based off of the same concepts.

These systems are useful whenever you have tasks to execute that depends on the existence or age of other files or you need prerequisite tasks performed first. A classic example is building a C/C++ application where it involves two or more phases. First the project source is compiled into object files and afterwards, those object files are linked together to produce a final executable. This implies that the executable can't be made until the object files exist. Following that, the object files can't be made unless the corresponding source files exist.

In web apps, this can be useful if your project needs to generate certain files and make sure they're up-to-date. For example, turning `.svg` vector file into say a png or jpeg. Whenever the `.svg` file changes the corresponding output needs to be regenerated to reflect that change. Another example, generating corresponding html and css files from say a custom template.

This differs from say a shell script where expressing this relationship isn't as easy. They can both execute the commands needed for the project but systems like Rake and Make does this more efficiently by running only what's needed. Expressing the same behavior in a shell script would require much more lines of code and it would not be as clean as the declarative approached used by the above systems.

Answer (score 0):

Rake is a framework for organising scripts that you may need to do various maintenance tasks. Rails comes with a few built-in tasks, that should give you an idea about the scope of the tool. Try running the command `rake -T` to see a list of the rake tasks available.